# Why only my PuTTY scroll slow on ubuntu 10.04 running under VMware?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, putty, performance, scrolling

Scrolling up in PuTTY is very slow even just after starting and connecting.

I've tried black listing the VGA16 frame buffer that showed on 'dmesg | grep -i frame' output. It is not used now but this does not help.

All my other applications run and scroll fine, including GNOME terminal that scrolls up very fast.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 under VMware 7.1.3 build-324285. The VM have all CPU cores and lots of RAM and storage.

I'm using PuTTY to connect to a development board via serial over USB line. Under windows PuTTY works fine with it.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this same issue on an actual system.  I gave up and used `screen` instead.

`screen /dev/ttyS0 115200` to connect to ttyS0 at 115200bps.

`minicom` also works well but requires some initial setup to become convenient to use.

Comment: Thx, screen looks great for my needs.